# QRCode Extraction With ZXing

Tags: c#, qr-code, zxing

Hi I'm trying to read QRCode from scanned images, but I'm getting a low index of extraction (19 extracted from 500 images) the code of extraction:

```
class QrExtractor
{
    public String extractFrom(Bitmap image)
    {
        using (image)
        {
            LuminanceSource source;
            source = new BitmapLuminanceSource(image);
            BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
            Result result = new QRCodeReader().decode(bitmap);
            if (result != null)
            {
                return result.Text;
            }
            return "Couldn't Extract";
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any improvements that I can apply to this?

Thanks

Comment: Would you mind sharing some of the images? Is there any way you can see or save the images after transforming them to bitmap so you can check if they look decent?

Comment: Sorry can't add images because of rep points.